# Does relative Kullback-Leibler divergence exist?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, references, joint-distribution, kullback-leibler

Suppose I have two multivariate normal distributions. I have computed the KL divergence ($d_{KL}(N_1, N_2)$).  Is there a way to measure a relative divergence between these two distributions?

For instance in a deterministic case, there is absolute error and relative error.
Let's say if KL divergence is analogous to absolute error, is there an analogous case for relative error.

Any references to literature would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What is the deterministic example you have in mind ? I don't see what could be interpreted as a deterministic analogous of a divergence between two distributions.

Comment: In the deterministic case, I'm thinking of having two non-stochastic vectors of finite dimension and I use any norm to measure how far away they are from each other. Then divide this difference by the norm of either one to get a relative difference. I know I can't think of distributions in the same manner (finite dimensional vectors) but is there an analogous relative divergence.